# Create a page for the Heading in Quick Launch

Tags: quick-launch, pages, sitepages

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm not even sure how to ask my question. I created links to some lists and libraries under some navigation headings. I understand how to add a URL to the headings, but I want to create a page that has my lists and libraries on it and use the URL to that page as the heading URL. I want to do this to give a better view of the lists and libraries under my headings than just the standard list/menu style that shows up under the heading.

I hope this makes sense. Is doing this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by header here? Can you add any screenshot for better understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create pages to display lists and libraries in different ways using web parts.  Once you have one of these pages created, you can use the page's URL as the link for the heading in the quick launch.  Sounds like you know how to do that in the Site Settings Navigation area.

The process for creating pages is conceptually the same in all versions of SharePoint.  Go to the Site Pages or Pages library (if you have Publishing enabled) and use the ribbon (2013, 2010) or menus (2007) to create/add a new page.  Then edit the page and insert "existing list" web parts for each existing list or library you want to include in your page.  Then configure each web part using the "Edit Web Part" menu and save your page.  If you have the publishing feature enabled you may also need to check-in and publish your page to make it visible to all users with access.

If you decide you don't want to use the existing list/library web parts then you could use the Content Editor web part and build your own HTML as needed.

Comment: That sounds great, I'll work on that. Thanks a lot!